# Can we pass data via props when pushing to a route in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, router, vue-props

I am asking this question to understand whether we can pass some data via props when navigating the new route. Because I read a few articles which recommend passing data as props and I want to understand if this really works.

As much as I looked into the [documentation](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode), passing props in routes works with only two cases-

1. When you want to use passed params as props.

```
{ path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true },
```

2. When you want to pass some static data.

```
{ path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: { value: 123 } },
```

In both cases, we use the props property in the route's definition.

**My question is if we want to pass some data via props when we push to a new route, is it doable? Because I tried this and noticed that passed props are always undefined. There is the same [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2210) that stated the problem but I didn't understand their last comment.**

Here is the demo which shows that passed props are always undefined in the template.

```js
const Comp1 = Vue.component('Comp1', {
  template: `
  <div>Comp1- <button @click="$router.push({name: 'Comp2',props: { value: 1234 },
      })">Push to route with props</button>
  </div>`,
});

const Comp2 = Vue.component('Comp1', {
  template: `<div>Comp2 - {{ value }} <button @click="$router.push({name: 'Comp1'
      })">Go back</button> </div>`,
  mounted() { console.log('Prop value- ', this.value) },
  props: ['value']
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      name: "Comp1",
      component: Comp1,
    },
    {
      path: '/comp1',
      name: "Comp2",
      component: Comp2,
    }
  ]
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.6.5/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: If you could provide in your post what you're trying to achieve, I can adjust my answer to suggest you a proper way to pass data to another route.

Comment: Hey, @nook. Thanks for your response. I won't pass data via props when pushing to the route. I just wanted to understand and make sure if this approach is possible or not because few articles recommend that it is doable, also,  in the documentation it is mentioned that props can be used to pass data but "passing props when pushing to the new route" example is not mentioned. A few answers also suggest passing data via props. So, I just want to clear up this doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is said is that you can't dynamically pass data to a route unless it's in the **parameters** of the route record or **statically provided**

##### What is a route parameter ?

A route parameter is a part of the url that should match something, but that is still tied to a given a component. For example, in this route record, `:id` is a route parameter. It's something that will be dynamic.

```ts
const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    name: 'user-detail',
    path '/users/:id',
    component: UserDetailView,
  },
];
```

Now, the props property in the route record is something used to read differently the parameter in the URL. You can achieve this in 2 ways:

```ts
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    id: string; // Route params are strings, I'm not sure if you can parse them first
  },

  // Composition API
  setup(props) {
    // Method 1
    const route = useRoute();
    const userId = route.params.id;

    // Method 2
    const userIdFromProps = props.id
  },

  // Options API
  created() {
    // Method 1
    const userId = this.$route.params.id;

    // Method 2
    const userIdFromProps = this.id; (this.id reads the prop id)
  },
});
```

##### What's the point of using props then ?

I may be wrong, but the only use case I see is when you want to use a **component** as a route's view.

You have a component that accepts props that you use in another view. And this component matches exactly your requirements, so instead of wrapping it in a view, you directly use it as a route's view, and props are automatically passed down.

##### My thoughts

Given my experience in many apps built with vue, this is something that rarely happens. Params in the route url usually match a ressource's ID, and you usually fetch it before passing it down to a component. So I'd use a wrapper anyway and would never use props on route records.

##### The answer:

After all those explanations I forgot to answer, because the question shouldn't have to be asked:

You can't pass props when pushing to a new route. The props will be read either from the URL if you use `props: true` in your route record, or from the route definition (record) if you statically defined it.

If you want to push data:

- Either you provide the resource id in the URL to let the page you're pushing to fetching it
- Either you save it in the `localStorage` (not recommended, that means your app architecture is maybe not adapted to your needs), and retrieve it on your next page

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Agree with the above points, and got the answer as well that it is not possible if it's not available in the route's record.